# use Angular 2 router to pass different values to the same component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

> The code below serves the same component `AppComponent` for three different routes, including `/`, `/route2`, and `/route3`.
>
> The problem is that the `title` and `bodyHTML` properties of `AppComponent` do not change values when the different routes are selected.
>
> **What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the app will serve different values for `title` and `bodyHTML` when each of the different routes are selected by the user?**
>
> Below are the steps to **reproduce the problem** on any computer **in a few minutes**:

---

**Create the Seed App:**

---

First, I created a seed app using Angular-CLI in the following steps:

```
cd C:\projects\angular-cli
ng new routes-share-component
cd C:\projects\angular-cli\routes-share-component
ng serve
```

---

**Change Only 4 files:**

---

Next, I changed only 4 files as follows:

I added `app.routing.ts` with the following content:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AppComponent },
    { path: 'route2', component: AppComponent },
    { path: 'route3', component: AppComponent }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

I changed `app.component.ts` to become the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  title = 'This is the title!';
  bodyHTML = 'Here is the content!'

  constructor(private _router:Router, private route:ActivatedRoute) { 
      console.log('inside the constructor!');
      console.log(route.url);
      console.log(_router.url);
 }

 ngOnInit() {
     console.log('inside ngOnInit()');
     let currentUrl = this._router.url; /// this will give you current url
     console.log(currentUrl);
     if(currentUrl=='/'){this.title='Home Page Title';this.bodyHTML='Body goes here.';}
     if(currentUrl=='/route2'){this.title='Route 2 Title';this.bodyHTML='Body goes here.';}
     if(currentUrl=='/route3'){this.title='Route 3 Title';this.bodyHTML='Body goes here.';}
     console.log(this.route.url);
 }
 ngOnChanges() {
     console.log('inside ngOnChanges()!');
     let currentUrl = this._router.url; /// this will give you current url
     console.log(currentUrl);      
     if(currentUrl=='/'){this.title='Home Page Title';this.bodyHTML='Body goes here.';}
     if(currentUrl=='/route2'){this.title='Route 2 Title';this.bodyHTML='Body goes here.';}
     if(currentUrl=='/route3'){this.title='Route 3 Title';this.bodyHTML='Body goes here.';}
     console.log(this.route.url);
 }

}
```

Similarly, `app.component.html` was simplified into the following:

```
<div style="text-align:left">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>{{bodyHTML}}</p>
</div>
```

And `app.module.ts` becomes the following, with `app.routing.ts` included:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Note that the `ngOnInit()` block prints in the console, but that the `ngOnChanges()` block does NOT.  This means that the title is always `Home Page Title`, no matter which route is selected.

**What specific changes need to be made to the above code so that each route prints different values in the browser for `title` and `bodyHTML`?**

---

**@BeetleJuice's suggestions:**

---

Per @BeetleJuice's suggestion, I tried the following new version of `AppComponent`, but it is showing compilation errors at the lines `routerSub:Subscription`, and at the line `this.routerSub = this.router.events.filter(....)`.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd, Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';  
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';  

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'This is the title!';
  bodyHTML = 'Here is the content!';
  routerSub:Subscription;

  constructor(private router:Router) { 
      console.log('inside the constructor!');
      console.log(router.url);
   }

  ngOnInit(){       
    // listen to NavigationEnd events
    this.routerSub = this.router.events.filter(e=>e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      // capture the new URL
      .map(e.NavigationEnd => e.url)
      .subscribe(url => {
        /* TODO: use URL to update the view */
      });
  }

  // When the component is destroyed, you must unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.routerSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**What else needs to be changed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you need to realize:

- When Angular navigates to a new route that uses the same component, it does not re-initialize the component. So your `ngOnInit` runs only the first time the component is loaded.
- ngOnChanges is **not** triggered when any component property changes. It is triggered when a data-bound property (as denoted by `@Input() someProp`) is changed by a parent component. [See the docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-ngonchanges).  So your `ngOnChanges` is not getting triggered either.

One way to update your model when the route changes but the Component doesn't is to inject the Router, listen to the `Router.events` observable and react to the route change there

**app.component.ts**

```
import {NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
...

routerSub:Subscription;

ngOnInit(){       
  // listen to NavigationEnd events
  this.routerSub = this.router.events.filter(e=>e instanceof NavigationEnd)
    // capture the new URL
    .map((e:NavigationEnd) => e.url)
    .subscribe(url => {
      /* TODO: use URL to update the view */
    });
}

// When the component is destroyed, you must unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks
ngOnDestroy(){
  this.routerSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

By the way, it may not be a good idea to have multiple routes that resolve to the same component. Consider having one [parameterized route](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter) instead!

Comment: In which class from the OP do I add the code that you suggest?  And why might nit not be a good idea to have multiple results resolve to the same content?  The intent in this application is to have multiple search-engine-friendly routes which use the same template.

Comment: @CodeMed The code is meant to run in `app.component.ts`.  I know very little about SEO so I can't advise on how to make an Angular application SEO friendly. However you're using multiple route to solve the problem that route parameters were designed to solve. I don't know how having`/route1`, `/route2` is better for SEO than `/route/1`, `/route/2` (parameter at the end)

Comment: I just added a copy of the new `AppComponent` with your suggestions, and describing the remaining compilation errors.  What else do I need to change in it?

Comment: @CodeMed When you ask for help, please reproduce the error message if applicable.  Did you `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription'` ?

Comment: Adding the `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription` got rid of the first compilation error, but the `filter(..)` line still throws `[ts] Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'.`

Comment: @CodeMed This type of error is easy enough to resolve if you look into it. Basically, you need to import all the things that are not native Javascript. add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';` You will also need `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: Yes, I added those.  And now `.map(e => e.url)` is throwing `[ts]
Property 'url' does not exist on type 'Event'.  Property 'url' does not exist on type 'RouteConfigLoadStart'`.  I will keep updating the last section of the OP to show what I actually have now in `AppComponent`.

Comment: @CodeMed I've added type information to my answer (look at the `.map` line) to help Typescript see that the code is ok.

Comment: Funny.  Now the line `.map(e.NavigationEnd => e.url)` throws the compilation error `[ts] Cannot find name 'e'` at both locations of `e` on that line.

Comment: I wrote the OP from only 4 lines of Angular-CLI that make it easy to recreate on any computer in only a few minutes.  Probably a lot faster to re-create it than to wait for me to pick it apart. ..... Thank you very much so far.  I very much appreciate it.  I am just trying to save you time.

Comment: @CodeMed you did not copy my code correctly. Your error refers to `e.NavigationEnd`. My code has `(e:NavigationEnd)`

Comment: Thank you and +1 for educating all of us with your answer and your elaboration.

Comment: I have another Angular 2 question.  Are you willing to comment?  Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089353/angular2-apache-back-button-not-working-after-rest-served-blob